# How to Melt single column in R

Tags: r, reshape, melt

How to melt single column from T1 to  T2.

```html
T1   
Mar-17  T2 
328  Mar-17 328
29.57  Mar-17 29.57
38.483  Mar-17 38.483
31.26  Mar-17 31.26
37.3  Mar-17 37.3
60.026  Mar-17 60.026
47.059  Mar-17 47.059
40.215  Mar-17 40.215
51.79  Mar-17 51.79
45.284  Mar-17 45.284
41.271  Mar-17 41.271
42.411  Mar-17 42.411
```

and what id I should use to get output in T4 from T3

```html
T3    
Mar-17 Apr-17  T4 
328 396  Mar-17 328
29.57 216.57  Mar-17 29.57
38.483 116.483  Mar-17 38.483
31.26 168.26  Mar-17 31.26
37.3 128.3  Mar-17 37.3
60.026 82.026  Mar-17 60.026
47.059 113.059  Mar-17 47.059
40.215 165.215  Mar-17 40.215
51.79 80.79  Mar-17 51.79
45.284 185.284  Mar-17 45.284
41.271 183.271  Mar-17 41.271
42.411 204.411  Mar-17 42.411
   Apr-17 396
   Apr-17 216.57
   Apr-17 116.483
   Apr-17 168.26
   Apr-17 128.3
   Apr-17 82.026
   Apr-17 113.059
   Apr-17 165.215
   Apr-17 80.79
   Apr-17 185.284
   Apr-17 183.271
   Apr-17 204.411
```

When I am using stack

```
T2 <- stack(T1)
```

it is giving error message

> Error in rep.int(names(x), lengths(x)) : invalid 'times' value

Comment: Is Mar-17 the column name or the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce your error when I do not have column names (but rather have `Mar-17` and `Apr-17` as the first observation) so I am assuming that this is how your data is structured. If `Mar-17` and `Apr-17` are your column names, `stack()` should work.

In this case, you could set your variable names to be the values in the first row and then use `stack()` on everything excluding the first row:

```
names(T1) <- T1[1,]
T2 <- stack(T1[-1, , drop = F])

head(T2)
#       values    ind
#1     328 Mar-17
#2   29.57 Mar-17
#3  38.483 Mar-17
#4   31.26 Mar-17
#5    37.3 Mar-17
#6  60.026 Mar-17

names(T3) <- T3[1,]
T4 <- stack(T3[-1,])

head(T4)
#  values    ind
#1    328 Mar-17
#2  29.57 Mar-17
#3 38.483 Mar-17
#4  31.26 Mar-17
#5   37.3 Mar-17
#6 60.026 Mar-17
```

---

**Data:**

```
T1 <- structure(list(c("Mar-17", "328", "29.57", "38.483", "31.26", 
          "37.3", "60.026", "47.059", "40.215", "51.79", "45.284", "41.271", 
          "42.411")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))

T3 <- structure(list(c("Mar-17", "328", "29.57", "38.483", "31.26", 
          "37.3", "60.026", "47.059", "40.215", "51.79", "45.284", "41.271", 
          "42.411"), c("Apr-17", "396", "216.57", "116.483", "168.26", 
          "128.3", "82.026", "113.059", "165.215", "80.79", "185.284", 
          "183.271", "204.411")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Mike it worked well, you have been very generous to reproduce the data.